# AngularFire testing for an object to exist using RxJS Subject

Tags: rxjs, observable, angularfire

I am trying to test for an object to exist in my AngularFire table.  I am having issues returning the subject to detect if the file exists or not.

```
/**
 * Check if the Id exists in storage
 * @param Id string | number Key value to check
 * @returns Subject<boolean>
 */
public Exists(Id:string):Subject<boolean> {
    const Status$:Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

    let RecordExists:boolean = false;
    this.AfDb_.object<T>(`_Testing_/${Id}`).valueChanges()
        .subscribe( (OneRecord:T) => {
            if (OneRecord.Key_ !== undefined && OneRecord.Key_ !== null && OneRecord.Key_.length > 0) {
                RecordExists = true;
            }
        })
    ;
    Status$.next(RecordExists);
    return Status$;
}
```

This is always returning undefined.  My automated tests then fail as well.

```
it('should confirm a record exists in storage', fakeAsync( () => {
    let Exists:boolean;
    const Status$:Subject<boolean> = ServiceUnderTest.Exists('Good');    // This exists in Firebase
    Status$.subscribe( (Result:boolean) => {
        Exists = Result;
    });
    flushMicrotasks();
    Status$.unsubscribe();
    expect(Exists).toBeTrue();
}));
```

I have access in Firebase to /*Testing*/Good which is an object with a structure of Key_ and Name.

Modules from package.json

```
"@angular/fire": "^5.4.2",
"firebase": "^7.9.3",
```

However, if I simply try to return a result without going directly to AngularFire, these tests work.

```
public Exists(Id:string):BehaviorSubject<boolean> {
    const Status:BehaviorSubject<boolean | undefined> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean | undefined>(undefined);

    Status.next(true);
    return Status;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `next` on subject when `RecordExists` came from `.valueChanges()` e.g.:

```js
    let RecordExists:boolean = false;
    this.AfDb_.object<T>(`_Testing_/${Id}`).valueChanges()
        .subscribe( (OneRecord:T) => {


            if (OneRecord.Key_ !== undefined && OneRecord.Key_ !== null && OneRecord.Key_.length > 0) {
                Status$.next(true);
            } else {
                 Status$.next(false);
           }
        })
    ;
    return Status$;
```

Your code behave in different way in test and simple example because both are call this `.valueChanges()` in synchronous way so `.next()` is called after `subscribe`. In real life  valueChanges is async so `subscribe` is called before `next`.

====================Edited=====================

to connect with real database you have to modify your test to be async (because connection is async:

```js
it('should confirm a record exists in storage',((done) => {
    Status$.subscribe( (Result:boolean) => {
      expect(Exists).toBeTrue();
      done()
    });
d}))
```

Comment: I need this there, even though I am setting the variable that is declared outside the subscribe block?  The RecordExists is defined before the calls to AngularFire.  Is setting this in the subscribe block, the same thing?

Comment: Subject will not emit anything because variable was overwritten, you have to call `.next` method each time.

Comment: My test though still fails, indicating undefined is not true. The variable that is getting set 'Exists' in the test seems to not have its value either.  However, this is the final result I am trying to validate. Maybe I do not understand the every time aspect, as this is only a single object, not a list.

Comment: Are you sure that `this.AfDb_.object<T>(`_Testing_/${Id}`).valueChanges()` was mocked in test?

Comment: I am not actually mocking this. I am trying it with a real database, and that is a path that exists with data.  I was trying the real database to ensure my test worked without a mock, to remove one level of possible errors. I should add that doing a console.log in the service function will show the data exists.

Comment: Understood. If you want to test with real database connection you can not use `flushMicrotasks` because connection has to be async. Check edited section.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209340/discussion-between-steven-scott-and-przemyslaw-jan-beigert).